# Geoserver unavailable in Geonode instalation after restarting Tomcat

Tags: django, tomcat, http-status-code-404, geoserver

I have installed geonode in a production server and it was working correctly after i execute:

```
systemctl restart tomcat.service
```

After this geoserver stop working. If i open the url mydomain.org/geoserver appears a tomcat 404 status.

Maybe after the restart the webapp is not linked correctly?

Any idea why this is?

Thanks

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your interest, in the logs i found several warnings about problems with beans creations, and "Can't access to geoserver data folder", after several time of investigation i decided to reinstall Geonode, leaving the database intact, and saving the geoserver data folder to replace it in the new installation. Python versión in Geonode last versión was updated, so my thought is that, restarting Tomcat maybe updated something in Geoserver with the new requirements for python and crash the connection with geonode.